# MySQL select with alias

Tags: mysql

i have error on sql statment

```
SELECT temp.*  FROM 
    (SELECT th1.process_id,th2.process_id FROM `thread` as th1,`thread` as th2
    where (th1.thread_id=th2.thread_id)and 
    (th1.process_id!=th2.process_id) and 
    (th1.analysis_id='".$analysis_id."' ) and  
    (th2.analysis_id='".$analysis_id."' )) as temp 
     where ((t emp.p1  NOT IN (select pr.parent_process_id from process as pr 
            wherer pr.process_id=th2.process_id and (th2.analysis_id='".$analysis_id."' ) 
                and (pr.analysis_id='".$analysis_id."' )))  
        or  (temp.p2  NOT IN 
                         (select pr1.parent_process_id from process as pr1 
                           wherer pr1.process_id=th1.process_id  and (th2.analysis_id='".$analysis_id."' ) 
and (pr1.analysis_id='".$analysis_id."' ))))
```

Answer (score 4):

You have an obvious syntax error using `wherer` instead of `where`.

```
wherer pr.process_id=th2.process_id and
```

Should be

```
where pr.process_id=th2.process_id and
```

When MySQL reports an error similar to *Check the manual for the correct syntax to use near...*, look exactly to that location or to the character immediately before it for your syntax error.

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'wherer pr.process_id=tem.p2